# IK Rig is broken on one half

Tags: inverse-kinematics

A very common IK rig problem I always get is that on one half of the rig ( in terms of circular movement of the empty ) the rig completely glitches and behaves broken. It is flipping around and does not correctly behave at all like on the " right " half

I have recorded a little video showing what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8X0-qnsgPu0

For Additional clarification. This ALWAYS Happens to me in some way or form. I have never had an IK Rig that does not flip.

Edit: I have added a pole target which helps the Rig rotate without the glitching. But it is still flipping around.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoukPw-UfeY

Can you please help me out with that as well?

Edit2: I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION!
I have added a " Child of " Constraint to the pole bone and set the father to the first bone in the Chain. Moving the control empty now results in the Whole rig animating Like I want it to without glitching or flipping.

Comment: If you use Pose mode to inspect each bone, do you have any "Bone Constraints" like *Limit Rotation*?   Such constraints could cause this.

Comment: @james_t Thank you for the Idea, but that is not the Case. The only constraint is the IK constraint on the last bone.

Comment: If your IK bone has no Pole Target bone, at some points it doesn't know how it is supposed to bend, I guess it's your problem here

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the Tip, that fixed glitching behavior, but it still flips when meeting the diagonal direction of the pole bone. I have added another Video in the Main question description showing what I mean.

Comment: there's still an ambiguity on how it is supposed to bend towards the pole target, you need to move the pole target so that it always makes the knee bend in the direction you want

Comment: @moonboots How exactly and with which Constraints do I do so? Do you have a Step by Step list or a video showing this?

Comment: you just need to animate the pole target bone, please share your file

Comment: @moonboots Never mind, I actually found the solution myself. I have added a " Child of " Constraint to the pole bone and set the father to the first bone in the Chain. Moving the control empty now results in the Whole rig animating Like I want it to without glitching or flipping. Thank you for pointing me into the right direction with the pole target.